# Untrusted Application Launcher

Tags: permissions, launcher, security

So I'm trying to create a desktop icon for an application, and I dragged it from the top-left menu (I think it's called Dash or something). I clicked on it and it says it is untrusted and refuse to execute it.

I found out that [I have go to Permission and check the checkbox saying "Allow executing file as program"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10395/untrusted-application-launcher). However, when I open up the Permission dialog it says "I am not the owner, therefore I cannot change those settings." Everything is disabled and I can't check it.

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I "make myself the owner"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> then run this command:

  ```
  cd ~/Desktop
  sudo chmod +x sublime_text.desktop
  ```

  Change `Desktop` to whatever your desktop is called in your language. 
  [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) is a command line command to change permissions, `+x` make it executable
- or instead you can run:

  ```
  cd ~/Desktop
  sudo chown yourusername sublime_text.desktop
  ```

  [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) is command line command to change file owner

Comment: Thanks this works. The shortcut becomes executable when set it via command line, but when I try to do it to change file owner it doesn't work

Comment: you have changed "yourusername" with your username on the system.

 try: sudo chown yourusername:yourgroupname sublime_text.desktop

to change the group too (group name is same as username, most desktop linux)

Comment: Yes I did change it. I figured it out, I have to re-login to see the effect. It worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in the terminal: `gksu nautilus`
2. Enter your password when prompted and your file browser should emerge.

   This will make you root until you close the file browsing window, which is necessary to edit the file (as you can see that only "root" has permission.
3. In here navigate to the file you want to edit. Now you can set the file to execute as program.

Be advised to use `gksu` with extreme caution. Everything you delete will be deleted permanently. Making changes to the wrong files is really easy this way and could leave you with an unusable system!

This is AFAIK about getting ownership of a file that belongs to *Root*

Comment: It does open up the file browser but when I navigate to Desktop there's nothing there.

Comment: Yeah, Because you run it as user **root**. So the one you see empty is `/root/Desktop/`. Your user should be in `/home/yourusername/Desktop/`.

Comment: Is my answer not usefull at all? I'd like to know so don't hesitate to downvote if it didn't help.

Comment: It should work, That's why I think @Derek朕會功夫 may missed the folder as default for root is `/root/Desktop`.

Comment: @Nkciy84 I believe that's the problem, sorry for the slow response, and thanks for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an answer:

- Open Terminal
- Type `sudo -H nautilus`
- Ignore the messages, go to the opened Nautilus
- Open the Desktop folder
- Find the icon for your "untrusted program"
- Right click the icon
- Select **Properties**
- Click the **Permissions** tab
- Check the box by **Allow executing file as program**
- Reboot