# Untrusted application launcher (symlink)

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher

I have tried:

[Untrusted Application Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388520/untrusted-application-launcher)

and

[Untrusted application launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10395/untrusted-application-launcher)

neither of above applies to this case, as I made a symbolic link:

```
/usr/share/applications$ ls -la onboard.desktop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 326 Apr  7 12:21 onboard.desktop

~/Desktop$ ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lj lj   39 Jul 26 22:22 onboard.desktop -> /usr/share/applications/onboard.desktop
```

unity claims owner is root, and as it may be noted x flag is on.

finally this was working until last update (yesterday)

14.04lts/unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is owned by root on your system,this location is in the root file system /usr/share/applications/onboard.desktop. Try this

1 make a new folder in your home folder and put your .desktop in this new folder

2 open a terminal and type `sudo -i` and enter your password

3 Type `cd` then drag and drop the new folder you made on the terminal, this will enter that folder.

4 type `chmod +x onboard.desktop`

This will change the permissions of the file as root and should allow your user access to the file.

NOTE any file you see with a little padlock icon is owned by another user

Please look here for how to properly make a .desktop [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Comment: from your answer I figure that it is better to copy .desktop file than to sym-link it. Indeed `cp /usr/share/applications/onboard.desktop ~/Desktop` did create launchable icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 18.04: `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, owned by root with permissions `644`, and a link to it in many users desktop.
If a user double clicks on the link in their Desktop directory, the "Untrusted application" dialog pops up, because (I think) the link is treated as a normal file, which can't be executed in `/home` or `/tmp` directories without executable bit set, as explained in:
[Permission of a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/)

To fix this, a `chmod +x /usr/share/applications/app.desktop` was sufficient.