# "untrusted application launcher" in desktop shortcut

Tags: unity, launcher

Using 18.04 Desktop version I add a new desktop shortcut. However there is no icon and when pressing the shortcut I get the message 
"untrusted application launcher"
When I approve by pressing "Trust and Lunch" the program is starting BUT the icon still missing. Next time when I press the shortcut I get the same "untrusted application launcher" messsage 
Follwing previouse issues I did the followng:

1. make sure that the desktop shortcust is executable 
   [Untrusted application launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10395/untrusted-application-launcher/10403)
2. the icon is valid and in the correct path
3. on another compute the same desktop scripts works
4. I am the owener of the desktop shortcusts and the directory  ./local/share/gvfs-metadata/home*
   [Untrusted Application Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388520/untrusted-application-launcher)

Where can I find more infoamtion about the cause of this issue ?

Moran

Comment: Edit your question to make it more precise what you ask. The header of your question should match what you actually want to ask.