# 17.10 / 18.04.TLS .desktop files are no longer trusted

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, 19.04, .desktop

I've moved from 17.04 to 17.10 (by update, not fresh install)

I have a bunch of customized `.desktop` files in my desktop.

When I try to run then, I get a message telling me these are "untrusted", and I have to retrust them manually.

Is there a way to trust them all?

note:

- desktop files have executable bit set (I have run `chmod +x`).
- before trusting they appear as a generic file, after with proper icon (e.g. terminal, browser, ...)
- worked fine before (that is icons and action were OK in 17.04)
- desktop to samba share are OK.

edit:

- files are not located in `/tmp` neither in `$HOME`.

I have read :

> **Execute-Permission Bit Required**

> - Applications, including desktops and shells, must not run executable code from files when they are both:
>   - lacking the executable bit
>   - located in a user's home directory or temporary directory.

- my desktop are in neither of those.

> - This includes *.desktop, *.jar, and *.exe files.

- .desktop files being `r--r--r--` or `r-xr-xr-x` won't execute.

> - Nothing may provide a workaround to run them anyway automatically ...

### Update

- 18.04 problem persist, accepted answer still work.
- 19.04 problem persist, accepted answer no longer work (you must replace yes by true, however after reboot, `.desktop` not executable)
- 20.04 use `true` instead of `yes` in accepted answer, or right-click "allow execution" from desktop (this might be troublesome for generated `.desktop`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission of a .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file)

Comment: @JoKeR I did set +x bit ..

Comment: Did you read the *policy* from the answer mentioned in that post?

Comment: @JoKeR I have that too, with files which permissions are set to 755 so this is not a dupe, its something new with 17.10

Comment: might be reported as a *bug* then...

Comment: Just on what to report it to? I did a fresh install only pulled over a few files and settings. Seems like an additional security layer. I have here a `.desktop` file I already trusted and when I delete it and pull over the same file from the backup, I have again to trust it. Checking the file with `stat`reveals that nothing is different between those both files. Maybe it has to do with lightDM not being the desktop manager anymore and gdm3 treating files with an extra security layer.

Comment: Same problem here, chmod 777 && chown ${USER} but still not "trusted", I hope it is a bug, otherwise it means they want us to manually "trust" every application which would be very irritating. The message is different from when the executable flag isn't set. I've included a screenshot trying to open the same file without (top) the executable bit and with (bottom) the executable bit. https://imgur.com/a/dKEaJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my desktop files being mentioned in a binary file called `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home` which I could not edit. However, after some digging, I found the `gio` command. Run the following command followed by doing a refresh in nautilus

```
gio set yourfile.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes
```

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: hardest part was to find F5 command to refresh desktop :(

Comment: It worked for me, but only AFTER I did a refresh. This has been an irritation to me for several weeks before I finally found this solution. I hope it works for everyone.

Comment: for all icons, do this `ls -1  ~/Desktop/*.desktop | xargs -i  gio set "{}" "metadata::trusted" yes` and then hit the `F5` key to refresh

Comment: I think this no longer works in 18.04 or 18.10. I don't know what the new solution is.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with this disgusting "Gnome" I was partly successful doing this:  copy (not link) the .desktop from /usr/share/applications/ into /home/user/Desktop ; make it owned by user ; make it x-ecutable for all ; then run the gio command as shown above ; thanks a lot @knb for the great little helper ( ls -1  ~/Desktop/*.desktop | xargs -i  gio set "{}" "metadata::trusted" yes )  great (& lets hope for a soon end of pain called "GNOME").

Comment: As far as I know, this no longer works on 20.04+.