# cubic: add custom favourites to gnome3 left panel; .desktop launchers untrusted on ~/Desktop

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons, .desktop

When creating a custom 18.04 iso with cubic, is there a way to add custom favourite application launchers in the left side gnome3 bar? I found that by adding a known launcher there while having booted the live cd, i can find it's name in .config/dconf/user, which is a binary file, that is not something i believe to be editable by hand. Also, i would like to add the modified favourites list to /etc/skel.

Another problem I've ran into is .desktop launchers being untrusted; if i put a desktop launcher in /etc/skel/Desktop/test.desktop, and then boot the customised live cd, the launcher's icon shows some default icon and doubleclicking it asks to mark it as trusted, and only then it switches to showing the actual icon of the launcher. Can this be fixed so as to not require the user manually marking it as trusted first?

chmod a+x does not help. Trying 'gio set test.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes' (as per [17.10 .desktop files are no longer trusted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted) ) does not work and returns metadata::trusted - entry does not exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
gio set path/to/launcher.desktop metadata::trusted yes
```

gio will return "metadata::trusted - entry does not exist." if superuser or another user is executing the command.

Also make sure user have the ownership of ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/

Following command will revert the permission if you have executed gio with root.

```
sudo chown -R username ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/
```