# After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS all my .desktop launchers went "Untrusted"

Tags: command-line, .desktop, executable

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS all my `.desktop` launchers went "Untrusted", and I have to "re-trust" them manually.

While many other posts (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/995690/480481)) say to use the command in terminal:

```
gio set YOURFILE.desktop "metadata::trusted" yes
```

I wanted to do this for all my `.desktop` files in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

I used the this command successfully:

```
ls *.desktop | xargs -Ifile gio set file "metadata::trusted" y
```