# What exactly makes a .desktop file launchable?

Tags: launcher, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10, and I like desktop launcers. Yes, they are a pain to make now that `gnome-desktop-item-edit` is a thing of the past, but I manage. Most often I copy a `.desktop` file from another machine, or I create a new one by hand... But where is the setting stored that makes it launchable? It is NOT stored in the launcher file itself (no changes after it is made launchable), it is also NOT stored in the file permission bits. To launch the program I have to right-click on the launcher and select `allow launching`. I hate it! This changes something somewhere in my directory structure, but what? I haven't done a recursive grep to search for this – I don't know what to look for in that case. Hoping for a pointer here instead, so I can make the thing launchable when I create it. Thanks!

Comment: I've been trying for some time and gave up, however see : https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-18-04-tls-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted

Comment: You too, what a shame ;) I'm hoping someone will come up with an idea!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1264333/66509 and do not use GNOME Shell for real productive work.