# Steam installer won't install

Tags: 16.04, steam

I'm trying to install steam but when i click the steam installer "install" button nothing happens. After a couple of tries this appeared and it stayed this way all night.

[image]
<sup>**↑4th icon down**</sup>

Edit: I have tried all the suggestions here but nothing worked. Though i did find this,[Steam:steam.desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8narD.png) when i try t save the document it tells me that the file location doesn't exist. Does this help at all?

Answer (score -1):

<s>Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!</s>

I have had the same problem with DEB files before, and the project is usually missing dependencies. Try running `sudo apt install -f` in the Terminal to install these missing dependencies. If that doesn't work, try running the file via the command line by typing `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/steam-installer` where /path/to/steam-installer is the file path to your DEB file. I have sometimes found that for no apparent reason, installation from DEB files works from the Terminal when it does not work in the GUI installer.

**EDIT:** After misunderstanding @xwing's question, I will now re-answer the question:

1. First, open the Terminal and type `cd /usr/share/applications`
2. Next, type `sudo chmod +x *.desktop`

Steam should now run properly.
Answer gleaned from the Ask Ubuntu archives, [Untrusted Application launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10395/untrusted-application-launcher)

Comment: neither of these worked. But when i searched both of my hard drives for "steam" this is one of the things that came up. The error happened when i tried to click on it.

Comment: After editing 4 times i realize i dont know how to post an image, sorry. what it says is that it is an untrusted application, and it needs to be marked as trusted, how do i do that?

Comment: is something noticeable supposed to happen after i type the second line? or does it happen in the background and i need to restart?

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart, but maybe you should restart your session, just log out and log back in again. The chmod command shouldn't output anything.