# How to make link open with non-default application

Tags: browser, default

I have made a desktop shortcut to a YouTube playlist, and it has a .desktop extension. How do I configure it so that it opens up with Mozilla Firefox, and not Google Chrome, which is my default browser?

(Reason being that YouTube freezes occasionally on chrome, running Ubuntu 18.04)

I do not want to change my default browser, as I still prefer Chrome.

Here are the contents of the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to 1. Introduction to Algorithms - YouTube
Type=Link
URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IAPZzGSbME&feature=youtu.be
Icon=text-html
```

I have tried right click and open with Firefox, but that doesn't stay permanently.

******TEMPORARY WORKAROUND******

- change the firefox homepage to the youtube playlist
- change the firefox icon to youtube icon (downloaded from google)
- add firefox to favorites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch it to an Application launcher and specify Firefox.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to 1. Introduction to Algorithms - YouTube
Type=Application
Exec=firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IAPZzGSbME
Icon=text-html
```

You will also need to mark it as executable. Some instructions are [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/10427/301745).

Comment: worked like a charm, although I ended up using my workaround because its just more convenient